# What To Do In this Step For All the Nodes?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am installing hadoop on a cluster of 4 machines having 1 namenode 1 secondary namenode and 2 datanodes. I am using cloudera manager for installing hadoop.I am on this page in the [Screenshot of my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lqiv.png) during my installation process. 
Do I need to click on and install "All Services" on all the nodes of the cluster including the secondarynamenode and datanodes or just the namenode?? 
If not "All Services" then which option should I choose to install on NameNode, SecondaryNameNode and DataNodes respectively....

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install the services on NameNode. You may also choose the "core hadoop" if you're not going to use HBase.

Comment: And what services do I need to install on secondarynamenode and datanodes???  Is it just sufficient to configure it in NameNode and just connect the other nodes in the cluster??

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Core Hodoop service if you want to install hadoop service only

To select the role of the machine click on the "Inspect Role Assignments" button available on the bottom right of the screen and modify the role of host.